# How is the holding force of this electromagnet so large?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetic-flux, electromagnet, iron-core

I am designing a system that uses the magnetic force to fix an object in its place. I plan to connect an I-core to my object and fix it to a fixed C-core by letting a magnetic flux flow through both cores. By using
$$E = \frac{B^2V}{2\mu_0\mu_r}$$
for the magnetic energy, with \$B\$ the flux density and \$V\$ the volume of the magentic core, my derivation for the magnetic force would be:
[image]
I drew an E-core, but it doesn't really matter for the derivation. The holding force is therefore given by:
$$F = \frac{B^2A}{2\mu_0\mu_r}$$

While searching for a magnetic core, I talked with several manufacturers, and they all said that the maximal saturation flux density of state-of-the-art materials is around \$B_{sat}=1.5-2 \text{ T} \$, which limits the holding force. I presumed that in order to increase the holding force, I must use a larger core (increasing \$A\$), but then I saw [this core from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JR6NRJO), which has a holding force of around \$1.2 \text{ kN}\$. If we assume \$B=2 \text{ T} \$, \$\mu_r=3000\$, and solve the equation for the holding force for \$A\$, we get \$A=2.2 \text{ m}^2 \$, which is much larger than the area of the electromagnet I saw on Amazon. What am I missing? It would have worked if the holding force term didn't contain \$\mu_r\$, which reduces the area to \$A=7.52 \text{ cm}^2 \$. Indeed, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_lock) says that the holding force is given without \$ \mu_r \$, but I don't understand why it doesn't include in the magnetic energy term.

Comment: @Arad You need to use `\$` and not `$` or `$$`. This is an *issue* for this site. You just have to memorize it. The `$$` does work but it occupies the entire line and doesn't work within a sentence. Just FYI.

Comment: there is a problem with editing on multiple SE sites ... the sites will probably go down for maintenance soon

Comment: @Arad \$\mu_r\$ isn't in the equation. So you worked that out, already.

Comment: Can you state what the parameters are in your equation (first one... I recognize the denominator of course but, E, B and V are still confusing me)

Comment: FYI, no need to go through a lengthy derivation: B^2 / (2 mu) is an energy density, which is also a pressure, the Maxwell stress.  Multiply by area and you have F simply.

Comment: @TimWilliams That's cool! I didn't know about the magnetic pressure. Thanks

Comment: @Arad You can use a backslash to escape the space that goes between a number and the unit, for example 1T is wrong, 1 T is the correct way. You would not write 12cats, you would write 12 cats.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would dispute that, the units are multiplied with the number, so there should be no space. The units are physical quantites, just like the base vectors. When you describe a vector you will not write 3 e_x (with e_x a unit vector); you will write 3e_x. It's a matter of taste and depends mostly on the person who taught you :)

Comment: If you must, units can be spaced most properly with a half-space U+2009, or `\,` in math mode. The units should be upright i.e. in a `\textrm{}` block.

Comment: @Arad - Hi, Solutions (i.e. answers) should be posted as *answers*, not be edited into the question. This is why Stack Exchange allows an OP to [self-answer](/help/self-answer). || Since your solution was inspired by someone else's answer, it is appropriate for you to leave their answer as the áccepted one (i.e. do *not* áccept your self-answer), but if you want to post your solution, that should be done in a self-answer. Can you please remove your solution from where you added it into the question, and post it as a self-answer instead? Thanks.

Comment: @Arad [NIST says](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/writing-si-metric-system-units) "A space is used between the number and the symbol to which it refers."

Comment: @AndrewMorton Ok, that's interesting. Ok, I'll follow the rules. I edit the post

Comment: @SamGibson I do it all the time when I post questions about circuits that don't work, and I always edit and show the circuits that worked at the end. I guess it's different if the question is pure theoretical. I'll add my solution as a seperate post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The holding force doesn't contain the \$\mu_r\$ term, because when you try to open the gap, you're computing the increase in magnetic energy **in the gap**, to differentiate with respect to distance, and the gap is vacuum, or at least air, which is much the same thing for magnetism.

You do use the \$\mu_r\$ term to compute the ampere.turns/m you need, the H field, to get the flux through the core in the first place, as it's the core that 'shortens the magnetic distance' round the core by a factor of \$\mu_r\$ compared to that in air.

It's worth having a handy conversion ratio to hand, for evaluating these door locks. If you have a 1 T field in the gap when closed, there is a pressure of 400 kPa, 4 atmospheres, 4 Bar, keeping them together. The pressure increases as the square of the field, so 16 Bar if you manage to get 2 T.

Comment: Thanks! you helped me find my way to the solution, I edit the main post

Answer (score 0):

My answer is inspired by the answer of Neil_UK. I (the OP) understand now where my problem was. The derivative I (the OP) calculated was for the magnetic energy in the core, but it's actually not the right term to calculate the energy. The total energy is given by:
$$ E = \frac{B^2V_\text{core}}{2\mu_0\mu_r} + \frac{B^2V_\text{gap}}{2\mu_0} $$
Where \$E_\text{gap} >> E_\text{core} \$. Now \$\text{d}V_\text{core} = 0\$ since it's a property of the core. Now if we continue the derivation like above (With \$ V = V_\text{gap} \$) we get the right term for the holding force:
$$F = \frac{B^2A}{2\mu_0}$$

Though I must say that the derivation with the method described by @Tim Williams is much simpler than what I did.